# How to execute commands in gnuplot using shell script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gnuplot

What I want to do is write a script which first launches a program and then tells it to execute a bunch of commands and then quit. Lets go with an example.
I wrote this script `myscript.sh` and it doesn't work the way I want it to. What it does is just run gnuplot and wait for it to quit and then runs the other commands; which obviously produces errors.

```
#!/bin/bash
gnuplot
plot sin(x)
pause -1
quit
```

I guess it is clear what I'm trying to do; if not, then let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From `man gnuplot` or [its online manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/gnuplot.1.html):

```
   -p,  --persist  lets  plot  windows  survive after main gnuplot program
   exits.

   -e "command list" executes the requested commands  before  loading  the
   next input file.
```

So what you probably want to run is the following command:

```
gnuplot -e "plot sin(x); pause -1"
```

---

Other variants I proposed but which are not that useful were:

```
gnuplot -p -e "plot sin(x); pause -1"
gnuplot -e "plot sin(x)"
gnuplot -p -e "plot sin(x)"
```

Comment: The first 2 produce exactly  the desired output. Although `-p` is not of much use in this example; if you press enter in the terminal, gnuplot exits and the plot window becomes completely non interactive, except for the quit command. Output of 3rd just comes and goes (not visible at all). The last one produces output, but since gnuplot closes immediately, the plot window is again non interactive (also, it shows a tiny 1square cm plot). So `pause -1` is necessary.

Comment: @MihirGadgil Thanks for the feedback. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 19):

One way is with `-persist`:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist
set title "Walt pedometer" font ",14" textcolor rgbcolor "royalblue"
set timefmt "%y/%m/%d"
set xdata time
set pointsize 1
set terminal wxt  enhanced title "Walt's steps " persist raise
plot "/home/walt/var/Pedometer" using 1:2 with linespoints
```

another way, if you need to preprocess data, is with a Bash `Here Document` (see `man bash`):

```
#!/bin/bash
minval=0    # the result of some (omitted) calculation
maxval=4219   # ditto
gnuplot -persist <<-EOFMarker
    set title "Walt pedometer" font ",14" textcolor rgbcolor "royalblue"
    set timefmt "%y/%m/%d"
    set yrange $minval:$maxval
    set xdata time
    set pointsize 1
    set terminal wxt  enhanced title "Walt's steps " persist raise
    plot "/home/walt/var/Pedometer" using 1:2 with linespoints
EOFMarker
# rest of script, after gnuplot exits
```

Comment: This (the "here-doc" shell method) is probably the generic answer the OP looked for. It will work for a lot of command-driven programs  (and if not, you can escalate to `expect`...

Comment: Moreover you can make executable the scripts with `chmod u+x myscript.gnu` and execute directly with `./myscript.gnu` 
Just a note you forget the `[]` in the yrange: `set yrange [$minval:$maxval]`.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the [`man` pages](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.0/gnuplot.pdf), `gnuplot` expects input from a command file in what is called an *batch session*. You can e.g. write the line `plot sin(x)` to a file `myplot` and then execute `gnuplot myplot`.

If you omit the command file, as your script does, you will get an *interactive session*.

Comment: Okay, I get it that its jumping into an interactive session, but is there no way to feed commands into that interactive session through the same sctipt? Also, could you give a more general answer (not specific to gnuplot)? Thanks!

Comment: No, not all applications process input the same way. There is no way to generalize that.

Comment: @MihirGadgil - not all programs work the same way... which other ones do you want to use?

Comment: @Jos Oh, I see, thanks!
Wilf I have used linux in the past but not extensively, now trying to learn more. I don't have any such programs in mind; just trying to learn as much as I can from this one problem.

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
{#set terminal postfile             
{#set output  "d1_plot.ps"        
set title "Energy vs. Time for Sample Data"    
set xlabel "Time"    
set ylabel "Energy"    
plot "d1.dat" with lines   
pause -1 "Hit Enter to continue"
```

[click here for more details](http://research.physics.illinois.edu/ElectronicStructure/498-s97/comp_info/gnuplot.html)

Answer (score 0):

The here-doc method mentioned is highly useful with Gnuplot and with many other programs as well. By using shell variables within the Gnuplot commands in the here-doc, you can parameterize your plots with inputs from your shell script's command line.  By cagily setting things up, you can mass-produce plots from vast troves of "big data." I used to produce consistent-looking scatter plots with 20,000 to 80,000 points PER PLOT in hundreds of structural dynamics finite analysis runs using exactly this method. It's a very powerful method.

Comment: To make your answer complete, could you add an example how to use the mentioned here-doc method?

Answer (score 0):

`gnuplot myscript.sh -`

The trick is to put a dash **'-'** at the end of the command line.

It will leave the interactive gnuplot command alive. So that you can continue to insert command manually.

Everything after your quit command will not be evaluated.